# retrieving data using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a beginner in r and I am not getting the proper output as I wanted. So please can anyone help me in traversing the data sheet. I want the sum of the column `pos01` when `InfoType =="BV1MP" ,V01Nbr == 215, Err = 20`.

My data looks like this:

```
INFO    VERSION V01 Name    05170303.sta    Start   14:00:40    End 15:00:41    
Type    Idx Nbr Err Pos01   Pos02   Pos03   Pos04   Pos05   Pos06   Pos07   Pos08   Pos09   Pos10
BV1MP   0   215 20  48  47  48  48  48  48  47  26  46  48
BV1MP   0   215 21  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 24  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   22  2   0
BV1MP   0   215 25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 26  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 27  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 28  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 29  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 30  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 31  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 35  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
BV1MP   0   215 36  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Please help me in getting the result using `for` loop.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide resuable data

Comment: `sum(df$pos01[df$InfoType == "BV1MP" & df$V01Nbr == 215 & df$Err == 20]` What do you need the `for` loop for? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I actually have many datasheets which is having data like i sent. i have to plot the graph for each error number against particular type ,particular V01 nbr and particular positions.for example if i select type="BV1MP",V01 nbr = 215 and  particular position ,it should give the behaviour of each error type in each sheet. If it is not clarified and if you are interested to help me out please mail me at deepikasr03@gmail.com

Comment: What is a "datasheet"? Your loop is not intended to do the calculation (which is easily done the way @LAP is pointing out) but rather reading the "datasheets" and storing the results of your findings in a way that you can produce the graph later?

Comment: You could store all your 'datasheets' (are they of class `data.frame`?) in a list and use the `apply` family (specifically `lapply`, or even `mapply` with multiple variables) to loop over the list. A `for` loop is most likely unnecessary.

Comment: Initially the datasheet was not of class data frame.Later i extracted the date ,time and prepared a datasheet which now of class dataframe @LAP  u please drop me ur mail id.please

Comment: can anyone help me in letting me know few more things? please drop me ur mail id here.please.it's my humble request @LAP

Comment: @Deepikasr Please join the [R Public Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public), I'm there for now (except for a quick lunch break).

Comment: I  cant talk there as I don't have 20reputations yet @LAP

Comment: Mail me at rhelpfordeepikasr@gmail.com